# How to change the Hive Metastore DB for Apache Spark using HiveContext in Local mode for unit testing?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, scalatest, metastore

I want to use *h2* instead of *Derby* as Hive Metastore DB for local unit tests, that run Apache Spark in local mode. 
`hiveContext.set("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL", connectionUrl)` setting not working cause hive context is initialized (and the metastore db also) earlier.
Setting on **SparkConf** is not working also. Could you help me?

Comment: Checking in 3 years later. Did you ever find a solution to this (local alternative to derby for the hive metastore)?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting this value as `--conf hadoop.hive.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=...` and it should work. But probably it will only allow you to change derby location.

I had the same issue preparing environment for unit tests and I was unable to use sqlite so I suppose derby is only supported local DB.

Comment: Checking in 3 years later. Did you ever find a solution to this (local alternative to derby for the hive metastore)?